# TextTheme fields not match Sketch project text styles

Tags: flutter, material-design, sketch-3

I use material design plugin for Sketch to design my app. Now I need to set up my app theme to completely satisfy my prototype. There is no issues with colors. But with text I see mismatch of fields of TextTheme class and generated by plugin styles

Material typography:

```
headline1
headline2
headline3
headline4
headline5
headline6
subtitle1
subtitle2
body1
body2
button
caption
overline
```

TextTheme fields:

```
body1
body2
button
caption
display1
display2
display3
display4
headline
overline
subhead
subtitle
title
```

What is the correct fields matching here?

Answer (score 2):

Found in [reference](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html):

```
NAME       SIZE   WEIGHT   SPACING  2018 NAME
display4   112.0  thin     0.0      headline1
display3   56.0   normal   0.0      headline2
display2   45.0   normal   0.0      headline3
display1   34.0   normal   0.0      headline4
headline   24.0   normal   0.0      headline5
title      20.0   medium   0.0      headline6
subhead    16.0   normal   0.0      subtitle1
body2      14.0   medium   0.0      body1
body1      14.0   normal   0.0      body2
caption    12.0   normal   0.0      caption
button     14.0   medium   0.0      button
subtitle   14.0   medium   0.0      subtitle2
overline   10.0   normal   0.0      overline
```